# segueForUnwindingToViewController throws excpetion for incorrect parent view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to run a custom segue for an unwind transition. There is an overall navigation controller, and two subviews (`ViewA` and `ViewB`). I am trying to go back between these with the following code (triggered via a button and a storyboard reverse segue):

```
// XXXNavigationController.h

- (UIStoryboardSegue *)segueForUnwindingToViewController:(UIViewController *)
toViewController fromViewController:(UIViewController *)
fromViewController identifier:(NSString *)identifier {
    UIViewController *controller = self.topViewController;
    return [controller segueForUnwindingToViewController:toViewController
                                      fromViewController:fromViewController
                                              identifier:identifier];
}

// XXXViewBController.h (in a reverse segue, going ViewB -> ViewA)

- (UIStoryboardSegue *)
segueForUnwindingToViewController:(UIViewController *)toViewController 
fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController 
identifier:(NSString *)identifier
{
    XXXReverseZoomSegue *segue = [[XXXReverseZoomSegue alloc] 
                                 initWithIdentifier:identifier 
                                             source:fromViewController 
                                        destination:toViewController];
    return segue;
}
```

This currently results in the following exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 
'child view controller:<XXXViewAController: 0x14c5119e0> 
 should have parent view controller:<XXXViewBController: 0x15000b400>
 but actual parent is:<XXXNavigationController: 0x14c5116a0>'
```

How can I set this up correctly so I can make the reverse segue work?

Comment: Do you know if you found a solution to this? I have the same setup and not getting an exception, but it hits `segueForUnwindingToViewController`, but it does not unwind.

Comment: Try this: `toViewController.parentViewController`